# access the exact view in a raw using js

Tags: javascript, php

My view has a button and the view is looped.so it has raws.
when i click the button of a single raw i need to color that button.
so i added a `onclick="select_Button(<?php echo $rawID?>)"`  to the raw's button in my view

select_Button is my funtion in js

```
function select_Button(rawNumberOfVote) {
            var RawNumber = rawNumberOfVote;
            alert ("Form submitted successfully" + RawNumber);
            var upVote = document.getElementById("up_vote");
            upVote.style.background = "green";

        }
```

like above i send the rawID to the funtion.
how can i edit this line to accept the view called up_vote in that particular raw id that i got from parameter.

`var upVote = document.getElementById("up_vote");`

becuz if i only use this line it will color the first raw's button instead the one i wanted

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use data attribute in your html referencing to [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp) and [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes). and retraive with this this jquery code snippet:

```
$("[data-test ='my value']")
```

or this code snnipet in javascript:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".example").find(function(dom){
     return dom.dataset.test == "expected-value"
});
```

**Update:**

accourding to [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_nodelist.asp) querySelectorAll return nodeList and NodeList are not array and we cannot use *find* method so I change my answer to this code:

```
<html>

    <body>
         <div class="post" data-key="1">
            <lable>test</lable>
            <button type="button" onclick="upvote(1)">up vote</button>
         </div>
         <div class="post" data-key="2">
            <lable>test</lable>
            <button type="button" onclick="upvote(2)">up vote</button>
         </div>
         <div class="post" data-key="3">
             <lable>test</lable>
             <button type="button" onclick="upvote(3)">up vote</button>
         </div> 
    </body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
     var upvote = function(id) {

         var nodes =    document.querySelectorAll(".post");
         console.log(nodes.length);
               for(i = 0 ; i < nodes.length ; i++){
                   console.log(nodes[i].dataset.key);
                   if (nodes[i].dataset.key == id)
                        nodes[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
                    }
        };
</script>
```

Comment: so you mean for .example i need to use my key  and for the expected-value i need to use my raw id . am i right?

Comment: yes that's right... you most set data attribute as your key and you find your element using that... let me know the answer and please check as answered if you got solution by this way

Comment: bah tried that no luck can you bit explain about the values that i need exactly to get the result with that java script code

Comment: good job and thank you for helping  accepting answer +^ voting it works with the second way